# Setting width of ComboBox autocomplete

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

In the WinForms combobox, the width of the drop-down can be set programmatically, as in the following example, code and screenshot:
`myComboBox.DropDownWidth = 300;`

[image]

For the combo box, I have enabled the autocomplete:

```
myComboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
myComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

The autocomplete drop-down appears as follows:

[image]

How can I set the width of the drop-down containing the suggested items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is not possible. You'll probably have to create a custom control to achieve what you need.

Here some information that might be useful for you:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f88f37c9-95f9-4f2f-84b5-e262f49a009d/autocomplete-suggest-box-can-this-be-influenced?forum=winformsdesigner